# Ploty R add_trace with for loop overwrites trace from get(Variable)

Tags: r, for-loop, plotly, bar-chart, r-plotly

I want to add traces to a Plotly bar chart for varying numbers of variables. Therefore I want to loop thru the variables. I do not get an error, but the variable of the latest loop overwrites the values of the former loops. It looks like this (V3 overwrites V2 in plot1)

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:3,11:13,111:113))

plot1 <- plot_ly(df, x = ~ V1
                 , y = 7
                 ,type = 'bar'
)
for(i in c("V2","V3")){
  plot1 <- plot1 %>% add_trace(y = ~ get(i)
                               ,type = 'bar'
  )
}
plot1
```

but should look like this (V3 does not overwrite V2 in plot2)

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:3,11:13,111:113))    

plot2 <- plot_ly(df, x = ~ V1

                 , y = 7
                 ,type = 'bar'
)
plot2 <- plot2 %>% add_trace(y = ~ V2
                               ,type = 'bar'
  )
plot2 <- plot2 %>% add_trace(y = ~ V3
                             ,type = 'bar'
)
plot2
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this works (using df[,i] instead of ~get(i) which is a little bit annoying as df has already be defined:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:3,11:13,111:113))

plot1 <- plot_ly(df, x = ~ V1
                 , y = 7
                 ,type = 'bar'
)
for(i in c("V2","V3")){
  plot1 <- plot1 %>% add_trace(y = df[,i]
                               ,type = 'bar'
  )
}
plot1
```